# How to after json file already load and then load googlemap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, webhooks

I use googlemap by javascript callback function

```
<script>
jsonmap={};
jqxhr=$.getJSON("postheat.json",function(data){
return data}).done(function(data){
  jsonmap=data;
  return data;
});
function initMap(){
   mapjson.....;
}
</script>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initMap"></script>
```

But I find when I initMap, the json data is not ready yet. How to make sure the json data already loaded and then execute initMap function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `initmap` after the call is complete in `done` block:

```
jsonmap={};

jqxhr = $.getJSON("postheat.json",function(data){
            jsonmap=data;
            //try adding script to the page here:
            var s=document.createElement("script");
            s.src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initMap";
            document.head.appendChild(s);
        });

function initMap(){
   mapjson.....;
}
```

But I'm sure there is a better way. Try if you can get something from maps docs.

Comment: As I said, the mapload is callback, when the mapload finished it directionlly call initMap function. You mean I will call iniMap twice?